# Flex url path question

Tags: apache-flex

Currently moving a project Ive been working on to a dev server but for some reason its still looking at localhost. I've checked firebug in firefox and also in chrome developer tools and they both show the app looking at localhost. On the odd side I'm running the network monitor in Flash Builder 4.5 and it is displaying the calls going out to the correct dev path. I've even gone the route of displaying the WSDL path in a text field and it does display the correct dev path.

Code block..

```
  protected function preInitializeService():void
{
    _serviceControl.service = "ASCC";
    _serviceControl.port = "ASCCSoap";
    wsdl = "http://dev.mysite.com/services/ascc.asmx?WSDL";
    model_internal::loadWSDLIfNecessary();
}
```

Comment: Quantity "Looking at". You mean your SWF is trying to access a WSDL on localhost?  Show the Flex code where you create your WebService object / calls the WSDL.

Comment: Yes, the swf is accessing localhost rather than the dev path.  I set up the web service via the data/services tools.  I checked the service file it creates and it is pointing to the correct path.

Comment: The services config file is compiled into the SWF; so whatever paths you have in the services config are, in essence, hard coded into the SWF.  If you have specified localhost that would explain your issue.  The code you've added to your question does ot access a services-config file and should ping dev.mysite.com not localhost.

Comment: I did some digging and found the services-config.xml on the dev server.  Localhost wasn't listed as an endpoint but this is what was there..
<endpoint uri="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/Gateway.aspx" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>

Based on what youre saying, will I be able to hard code the path there and just recompile my swf or will it read the path without recompiling?

Comment: services-config on the dev server doesn't make a difference.  Are you specifying a services-config as an argument to your Flex compiler?  If so, that is the one you want to look at.  If not; then you aren't using a services-config file and nothing inside it will affect your SWF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got this worked out.  First, thanks to both of you for helping on this.  The error was actually being caused by the network monitor inside of flash builder.  I noticed something odd when I turned of IIS and I was still able to run my application.  After some digging it turns out that the localhost my swf kept looking for was actually flash builder.  Once I disabled network monitor, did a clean, and compiled the swf it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an AMF connection that references services-config.xml? Check that your services-config.xml channel endpoint is pointing to your correct server url and not to localhost.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little lost but I just started working with Flex recently, coming from just Flash.  I used the data/services tools to create the web service connection.  I posted the code above that was generated for the service.